# Unable to create sqlite3 database on windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a sqlite3 database on my windows 7 64 bit machine. I have downloaded sqlite-shell-win32-x86-3071502 from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html . After running the sqlite3.exe from the installed folder, I ran the following:

sqlite3 mytest.db;

But I am getting "Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error".

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you input the command in a sqlite shell (see below)

```
sqlite> sqlite3 mytest.db;
Error: near "sqlite3": syntax error
```

You got the error because it is not a valid sqlite command.
If you are creating a database called mytest.db, try input the command in a Windows command prompt, then you would be in the sqlite shell environment. To find out all the supported commands, input .help in the sqlite shell.

```
D:\sqlite> sqlite3 mytest.db
SQLite version 3.6.23
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .help
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Instead of just double clicking the SQLite.exe directly I opened a cmd prompt, navigated to the folder where the exe is present then executed the command sqlite3 mytest.db. Now it is working fine. I spent more than a day to figure this out! Wish the documentation is more clearly written.